# Adding dependency to kotlin-multiplatform libs published with gradle metadata

Tags: gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

I am trying to add a gradle dependency in my kotlin-multiplatform lib. The dependency is `com.soywiz.korlibs.klock:klock:1.9.1:`. If I use gradle 4.10.1 the one I was using previously, It works like a charm. But I want to use gradle 6 so that I can use it with the kotlin-multiplatform plugin 1.3.70
It fails with the error bellow:-

```
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':jsNpm'.
   > Could not resolve com.soywiz.korlibs.klock:klock-metadata:1.9.1.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Unable to find a matching variant of com.soywiz.korlibs.klock:klock-metadata:1.9.1:
          - Variant 'metadata-api' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.klock:klock-metadata:1.9.1:
              - Incompatible attributes:
                  - Required org.gradle.usage 'kotlin-runtime' and found incompatible value 'kotlin-api'.
                  - Required org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type 'js' and found incompatible value 'common'.
              - Other attribute:
                  - Found org.gradle.status 'release' but wasn't required.
```

What do I do to get this error resolved?

Comment: In which "XXXDependencies do you have add klock:klock ?
Can you give us the whole kotlin {
    sourceSets { of your build.gradle?